# Limit Access of GitHub or Bitbucket Repository

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket, gitlab

Is there any way to limit the access of bitbucket or Github repository from a specific IP Address.

Which means I want to access my organisation repositories only from my office.

The another this is that is there any way to block with a time being?

Any of the git providers supporting this feature?

The SSH key is only useful for the git action without entering passwords and username?

Any way to solve this issue?

I think many of the IT Companies are using this service for securing their source code.

Is it possible to achieve this without a git service?

Comment: Not specific IP address but you can limit it to only certain accounts (accounts you haven't invited will not be able to view or check out your code). This is the paid feature.

Comment: but @slebetman, when he out from office he can access the repo .. that is the issue for me.

Comment: Hmm.. normally I'd consider that a feature. Most companies nowdays expect their employees to be able to access code from anywhere. See Tim's answer for a solution for github. One alternative is to host the repo on your own server using something like gitolite or gitlab. Then you don't even have to expose your code on the internet. Just host it in your LAN.

Comment: @slebetman, I want to know more about to hosting repo in other server as u said. can u please tell as detail, please give your mail id.

Answer (score 6):

BitBucket [does not appear](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/3717/limiting-repo-access-by-ip-address-bb-3715) to currently support access limitation by IP address:

> We don't have any plans to add this feature in the short term, but it's a good idea. We'll leave this issue open as a feature request.

GitHub Enterprise [does appear](https://help.github.com/enterprise/11.10.340/admin/articles/restricting-ssh-access-to-specific-hosts/) to support limiting access by IP address:

> Whenever you add an SSH key to GitHub Enterprise via the Management Console, you can also specify which IP addresses to allow or deny connections from.

As to why BitBucket is in no rush to add this feature, we can look at the model upon which Git was built.  One major feature of Git is that it allows for truly distributed development, across locations and IP addresses.  A developer can contribute at home, in the office, or on the road, requiring only an internet connection.  He can even continue making commits *without* an internet connection.

Comment: that means github is supporting with ssh keys right ?

Comment: As far as I know, yes it supports with SSH keys.

Comment: can you please share a link for setup this one

Comment: Check the GitHub [link I already gave](https://help.github.com/enterprise/11.10.340/admin/articles/restricting-ssh-access-to-specific-hosts/).  It has details for how to configure your SSH keys to restrict by IP address.

Comment: let me check, pls hold on

Answer (score 1):

Note: GitLab 12.0 (June 2019) does have the "[Restrict access by IP address](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/06/22/gitlab-12-0-released/#restrict-access-by-ip-address) " feature.

But only for [Ultimate](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/#self-managed) (self-managed) or [Gold](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/#gitlab-com) (gitlab.com) editions.

> Compliance-minded organizations may want to prohibit traffic from outside IP addresses from accessing company resources.
> This is especially helpful for organizations using VPNs, as you’re now able to restrict traffic from outside a specified subnet from accessing a group’s resources in the GitLab UI.
>
> Configurable at the group level on both self-managed and GitLab.com, maintaining tight control over your organization’s most valued code just became easier than ever.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/12_0/restrict-group-by-ip.png]

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/index.html#ip-access-restriction-ultimate) and [`gitlab-org/gitlab-ee` issue 1985](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/1985).

---

[GitLab 15.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/07/22/gitlab-15-2-released/#enforce-ip-address-restrictions-for-git-over-ssh) (July 2022) adds:

> ### Enforce IP address restrictions for Git over SSH
>
> Limiting access to requests from a trusted set of IP addresses may improve security.
>
> Until now, only the API and UI supported such access restrictions; SSH access was blocked entirely.
> SSH now also adheres to this restriction, and grants access only to requests coming from IP addresses in your list.
>
> [image: IP restriction]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/#group-access-restriction-by-ip-address) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/6296).

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket added the new features in IP based access repository. IP based access to the repository in bitbucket, you need to purchase the premium version of bitbucket ($5/per user/month). By these, you can restrict the access to the repository by another network.

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Bitbucket documentation on whitelisting IP addresses - https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/control-access-to-your-private-content-862621261.html

Answer (score 0):

For [GitHub Enterprise](https://github.com/enterprise), the limit by IP is no longer only for SSH keys.

See "[IP allow lists are now generally available](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-03-10-ip-allow-lists-are-now-generally-available/)" (March 2020)

> **IP allow lists** are now generally available for GitHub Enterprise Cloud customers – allowing enterprise and organization owners to limit access to enterprise assets to an allowed set of source IPs.
>
> All authorization credential types, including personal access tokens and SSH keys, are filtered by IP allow lists for all apps, users, and roles with access to enterprise organizations.
>
> You may also use [IP allow lists with GitHub Actions self-hosted runners](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-enterprise-account/enforcing-security-settings-in-your-enterprise-account#using-github-actions-with-an-ip-allow-list).

See more at "[Managing allowed IP addresses for organizations in your enterprise account](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-enterprise-account/enforcing-security-settings-in-your-enterprise-account#managing-allowed-ip-addresses-for-organizations-in-your-enterprise-account)".

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the file **etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb** then find the **whitelist** variable, uncomment it and add the ip

```
gitlab_rails['monitoring_whitelist'] = ['xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx']
```

And find and edit the **custom_gitlab_server_config** variable with the ip

```
nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "
 allow xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
 deny all;
 location ~ /.well-known {
  allow all;
 }
"
```

Finally, reconfigure your gitlab with

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```